# Upgrading MacBook Aluminium to Mountain Lion. Fully supported? Or will it slow down?

Tags: macos, upgrade, osx-mountain-lion

I have a MacBook Aluminium late 2008 version: 2GHz Intel Core 2 Duo, 2 GB 1067MHz DD3.

Since Apple doens't provide updates for my mac anymore and other important apps (like Firefox) does the same, I'm willing to upgrade to Mountain Lion.

I'm not an expert and I'm wondering if upgrading my mac will slow down it or if there will be any other important warnings.

Comment: Is it there in the list of supported devices?

Comment: Yes it is, it has the minimum requirements to run it.

Comment: If you are running Lion now, ML is definitely a worthy performance upgrade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same computer, and have gone from 10.6 to 10.7 to 10.8.

10.8 is faster than 10.7, but 10.6 is fastest.

If you have an iPhone/iPad, 10.8 is worth the upgrade from 10.6, in my opinion because of iMessage, notes, todo's, and all of the other iCloud syncing that it does.

Most apps will carry over, or have updates, you will have to look into what you use most and see if it's compatible.